# $A<_c B \implies P(A)<_c P(B)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Just started studying set theory. It's seems to me intuitivly correct that if $A<_c B \implies P(A)<_c P(B)$ where $_c$ is the cardinality of a set and $P(\cdot)$ is the powerset. Am I  right? I got confused of which injection to take from $P(A)\to P(B)$. Need some help.

Thank you.

Comment: What does $A <_c B$ mean? Is it "there is an injection from $A$ into $B$, but not *vice versa*"? If so, this is false. It is consistent that sets of different size have power sets of the same size.

Comment: I'm sure that this is a duplicate. But it's so much quicker to just write an answer instead... :\

Comment: $\mathrm{\LaTeX}$ tip: Please don't use `=>` for implication arrows. The proper way is to write `\implies`.

Comment: The comment "I got confused" at the end of the question makes me suspect that instead, you are simply asking whether $A\le_c B$ implies $\mathcal P(A)\le_c\mathcal P(B)$, where $A\le_c B$ just means that there is an injection from $A$ into $B$. If this is indeed the (much easier) question rather than what you actually wrote, it may be good to clarify.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo yes indeed i want to prove this $A\leq_c B\implies \mathcal P(A)\leq_c\mathcal P(B)$. any thoughts?

Answer (score 4):

No, this is not true.

It is consistent that $2^{\aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_1}=\aleph_2$. In that case you don't have the sharp inequality on the right hand side. What is true is that you always have: $$A\leq_c B\implies \mathcal P(A)\leq_c\mathcal P(B).$$

Comment: And how can i prove $A\leq_c B\implies \mathcal P(A)\leq_c\mathcal P(B)$?

Comment: If $f\colon A\to B$, what is the most natural of making it int a function from $\mathcal P(A)$ into $\mathcal P(B)$?